# Exponentially Distributed Random Variables is closed under multiplication with a positive number

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, exponential-distribution

A random variable $X$ is said to have an exponential distribution,

$f(x)\  =\  \begin{cases}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}&if\  x>0\\ 0&otherwise\end{cases} $

How can I show that the class of exponentially distributed random variables is closed under multiplication with a positive number

Or in other words, if $X$ is exponentially distributed and $α ∈ (0, ∞)$ how can I show that $ αX$ is also exponentially distributed.

Comment: Write down the CDF of $\alpha X$ and differentiate it to see what the pdf is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85554/is-the-family-of-exponential-distributions-closed-under-scaling